# Pandoc - pagebreak before bibliographu

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc, pandoc-citeproc

I'm trying to modify the default latex template so I'd get a newpage / pagebreak before bibliography when generating a pdf from markdown file (with bib file from Zotero and csl for styling).

I've been able to tweak the template so I'd get pagebreak after table of contents, but the can't figure out howto get it before bibliography (the thing I'm very new to latex is not helping either).

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

The command I use to generate file can look like this:

```
pandoc -s --bibliography samplebib.bib --citeproc --csl harvard-cite-them-right.csl loremipsum.md -o test_harvard.pdf -V lang=pl -M reference-section-title=Bibliografia --toc --template=./wit_mystyle.latex
```